# Redirecting when making a POST request

Tags: javascript, npm-request

I'm working on this piece of code which makes a POST request to an endpoint and then it should respond back with a simple JSON. here's my code:

```
var businessRulesOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  followAllRedirects: true,
  url: 'https://bpmrulesruntimebpm-*************hanatrial.ondemand.com/rules-service/v1/rules/invoke',
  qs: { rule_service_name: 'IoTManager::TemperatureService' },
  headers:
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'x-csrf-token': '*******************************' },
  body: [
    {   _type_: 'IoTManagerDataObjects',
        Temperature: 55
    } ],
  json: true };

request(businessRulesOptions, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

This code was generated with postman and it works perfectly through postman. however when i try to run it through command line, it returns the following response.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.
0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /></head><body style="background-color:#FFFFFF" onload="var url=window.location.hash;if(url&&0!==url.length){var anchorCooki
e='oucrsmziosknqgbubpwdsbwds_anchor=&quot;'+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&quot;';document.cookie=anchorCookie}document.forms[0].submit()"><p><script language="javascript">document.write("Please wait ...");</script></p><noscript><p>
Note: Your browser does not support JavaScript or it is turned off. Press the button to proceed.</p></noscript><form method="post" action="https://accounts.sap.com/saml2/idp/sso/accounts.sap.com"><input type="hidden" name="SAML
Request" value="PEF1dGhuUmVxdWVzd..."/><input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="oucrsmziosknqgbubpwdsbwds"/><noscript><input type="submit" value="Continue"/></noscript></form><
/body></html>
```

i looked up this error and it appears that it has something to do with redirecting when making POST requests. i added `followAllRedirects: true` but still no luck.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is that the entire output when run from the command line? What's in that form?

Comment: @robinsax I edited the post with the full response

Comment: The response you're getting is a webpage that uses javascript to submit a form to https://accounts.sap.com/saml2/idp/sso/accounts.sap.com. It has the keys `SAMLRequest` and `RelayState`. Are you sure you're using the API correctly?

Comment: @yaboiBrian : Did you find a solution?